# setting custom domain instead of 127.0.0.1 in Tornado application

Tags: python-2.7, tornado

I'm using Tornado Web framework for a school project and i wanted to use custom domain like `project_name.io` instead of the classic 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

I set an entry in my `/etc/hosts` file mapping `project_name.io` to `127.0.0.1` but i wanted to know if there were another way to deal with the domain without this.

As i am working with Windows user, adding a `--host=project_name.io` argument from the command line when running the development server would be a great solution. But it's not working on my side. And i think it's a DNS issue with the local DNS lookup.

Any idea about how i could set it up with Tornado ?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', MainHandler),
    ], **settings)

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8080, address='project_name.io')
```

documentation : http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.listen

Comment: I'm not currently in front of the code. But i'll tell you if it worked. Thanks